# Handling multiple entities in Solr

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, schema

Eventhough I am new to SOLR I was able to successfully index a single table
in a very short span of time. Now we have a requirement where the search
needs to happen on multiple tables (mutiple table indexes) at the same time.

I couldnt figure out a way to index more than one table in SOLR and search
on that indexed data. I tried using the below data config format but its
just indexing either of the 2 tables (and not both the tables).

DB-config.xml

```
 <dataConfig>
 <dataSource driver="com.metamatrix.jdbc.MMDriver" url="jdbc:....." />
 <document name="doc">
 <entity name="table1"
  query="select * from table1">
 <field column="ID" name="ElementID" />
 <field column="Name" name="ElementName" />
 <field column="ElementType" name="ElementType" />
 <field column="RepId" name="ElementRepId" />
</entity>

<entity name="table2"
query="select * from table2">
<field column="id" name="ElementPropertyID" />
<field column="Name" name="ElementPropertyName" />
<field column="DataType" name="ElementPropertyDataType" />
<field column="RepId" name="ElementPropertyRepId" />

</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>

Schema.xml

<fields>

<field name="ElementID" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" />
<field name="ElementName" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" />
<field name="ElementType" type="string" indexed="true"
stored="true" />
<field name="ElementRepId" type="string" indexed="true"
 stored="true" />

<field name="ElementPropertyID" type="string" indexed="true"
 stored="true" />
<field name="ElementPropertyName" type="string" indexed="true"
 stored="true" />
<field name="ElementPropertyDataType" type="string"
 indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="ElementPropertyRepId" type="string" indexed="true"
 stored="true" />


 <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" />
 </fields>

 <uniqueKey>ElementPropertyID</uniqueKey>
```

Can anyone help me out with a solution / pointers to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you have 2 separate entities.
Is there any relation between between table1 and table2..?
If yes then make it a single query with joins that should solve your problem.

For more information on the DataImportHandler please refer the below link.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Oracle_Example